# Outputting a specific place in a string to a variable

Tags: file, powershell, logging, character

I have a long log file that looks like:

```
2016-06-09 09:44:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext­
2016-06-09 09:45:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:46:33 3010 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:56:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:57:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
```

As you can see, at the 21st character of every line, there is a code showing if the application installed correctly. (0, 3010, or other numbers)

I just want to make it so all codes show up in a pop up window, making it easy to see if any errors are present.

I know how to make the pop up part, like this example:

```
$codes = "test text"

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("$codes", 0, "Test", 0)
```

Now, is there a way to "select" just the wanted characters of every line present in the file, let's say characters 21 to 24 so I can get an output like:

```
0
0
3010
0
0
```

in the popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the log as a CSV as a space-delimited file.  Then, select the 3rd column.

Example:

```
# Extract the codes from the file into an array
$codes = Import-Csv -path .\name.log -Header "date","time","code","type","file" -Delimiter " " |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty code

# Make sure each code is displayed on a newline
$formattedCode = $codes -join [Environment]::NewLine

# Display the codes in a popup
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup($formattedCode,0,"Test",0)
```

I tested this with this code based on the sample of the content of the file you supplied.

```
$content = @"
2016-06-09 09:44:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext­
2016-06-09 09:45:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:46:33 3010 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:56:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
2016-06-09 09:57:33 0 Appname C:\folder\file.ext
"@
$codes = $content | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "date","time","code","type","file" -Delimiter " " | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty code

$formattedCode = $codes -join [Environment]::NewLine

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup($formattedCode,0,"Test",0)
```

Comment: This sounds perfect, quite clever, but it doesn't work? I created a name.log file to match with your code so i could test it without altering anything and it returns: 


Import-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'file'.
At C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\test.ps1:3 char:21
+ $codes = Import-Csv -file file.log -Header "date","time","code","file ...
+                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: It runs correctly but returns empty, formatted code doesn't contain anything

Comment: to be precise, it returns 5 empty lines

Comment: Perhaps your file isn't the same as the sample content you supplied.  Adding a working example with the content you supplied.

Comment: Got it working, the problem was : 

Select-Object -ExcludeProperty code
it works with : 
select -ExpandProperty code

Comment: The final code is :

$codes = Import-Csv -path c:\temp\name.log -Header "date","time","code","file" -Delimiter " " |
select -ExpandProperty code

$formattedCode = $codes -join [Environment]::NewLine


$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup($formattedCode,0,"Test",0)

Thank you so much for your valuable help, learned a very nice trick thank to you :) Have a good day

Comment: Final question! How can i select two rows at once? for example code + file?

Comment: `-ExpandProperty` won't work for that.  You probably don't even really need it.  I assume you want a string that you will print for each line.  Replace the `Select-object` command with a `Foreach-Object { "{0}; {1}" -f $_.code, $_.file}`.  This will give you a string with `<code>; <file>`.  **Note:** I had a mistake in the header and file is not the file.  The header array needs to look something like this `"date","time","code","type","file"`.  I'll update the sample in a minute.

Comment: the foreach-object works absolutly perfect. I can manage the header it was still fine. This is now completly solved i will implement it tomorrow. Thanks a lot you saved an enterprise a lot of time with this :)

Answer (score 1):

short code :

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.Popup((import-csv "c:\temp\log.txt" -Header DateLog, TimeLOg, Code -Delimiter ' ').Code -join "`n", 0, "Test", 0)
```

if you want select only different 0 :

```
$code=(import-csv "c:\temp\log.txt" -Header DateLog, TimeLOg, Code -Delimiter ' ' |where code -ne "0").Code -join "`n"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.Popup($code, 0, "Test", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this (the different than 0, works wonders and nice short code! Much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't have enough reputation, i joined a few days ago only. Did it now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could split the lines at spaces, like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.log' | ForEach-Object {
  $date, $time, $code, $app, $file = $_ -split ' ', 5
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    Timestamp   = [datetime]"$date $time"
    Code        = [int]$code
    Application = $app
    File        = Get-Item $file
  }
}
```

or parse the lines with a regular expression, like this:

```
$re = '(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?<code>\d+) ' +
      '(?<app>\w+) (?<file>.*)'

Select-String 'C:\path\to\your.log' -Pattern $re |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Timestamp   = [datetime]$_.Groups['timestamp'].Value
      Code        = [int]$_.Groups['code'].Value
      Application = $_.Groups['app'].Value
      File        = Get-Item $_.Groups['file'].Value
    }
  }
```

Creating objects from the parsed values is optional, of course, but it might come in handy if you need to further process the data.

Comment: this code didn't work when i tried it inside powershell, it just showed every line of the file with timestamp, code and name like so :
2016-12-07 13:37:11                                       0                               VMware

Thanks anyway

Comment: Then you did something wrong, because both code samples worked just fine when I tested them with a file containing the sample data from your question. Without modification both code samples will just output the parsed fields from the input file in tabular form, though.